# How to have my footer expanded on the bottom of my window browser

Tags: html, css

I have a web site where I use a footer with a black background. On long pages, my footer is correctly adjusted on the bottom of my page. The problem occurs on small pages when I don't have any scrollbars. In this case, my footer in not at the bottom of my window browser and after the footer (with black background) we still see white background after the footer.

How can I proceed to have my black footer expanded until the bottom of my window browser?

Here is a live example: http://jsbin.com/okobeh/2/edit#javascript,html,live

On this example, you see my footer and below this footer we see white space.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you want `sticky footer` technique check this http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ .

Check this http://jsbin.com/okobeh/4/edit#html,live

Comment: Thanks. This seems an interesting solution. But what if I have also a header in my page like in this jsBin: http://jsbin.com/okobeh/5/edit

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed` and `bottom:0px`:  http://jsbin.com/okobeh/3/edit#preview

Comment: Thank you for your response. Maybe I didn't was clear. Your solution fixed the footer. So when vertical scrollbars are visible, the footer is still fixed on the footer. I would like the footer to be located on the bottom of my page (content). When the page content didn't completely fill the page, I don't want the footer to be located in the middle of the page. Hope this is a little more clear...

Comment: Yes, for the record, this solution here does this: "keep the footer at the bottom of the window irrespective  of other content".

Answer (score 0):

Lookup in the code of this example http://webmolot.com/recipe/css/element6/

If "position: fixed and bottom:0px" then add margin-bottom:{height_of_footer}px; to the content block (#body)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/Sz8ex/

Besides the changes to your CSS, I have added some HTML changes. An outer div that encloses the Header, Body and Footer.